# How to remove ElevatedButton?

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I have a question, how do I completely remove the button from the screen? I know that it is possible to disable it using Null, but this does not suit me, because it will still be displayed, albeit in the off state. I would like the button to be completely removed after a few clicks on it, how can I do this?

```
 ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _clickBloc.add(ClickUpdate());
                });
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap ElevatedButton with Visible Widget. And make Visible widget property to false after few clicks.

```
bool visibleVar = true;
Visibility(
  child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _clickBloc.add(ClickUpdate());
                  visibleVar();
                });
              },
            ),
  visible: visibleVar,
),

void changeVisibility(){
  visibleVar = ! visibleVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use conditional if with a bool like `bool showThisWidget = true`

```dart
if (showThisWidget) ElevatedButton(....)
```

If it is on child , most child accept null.

```dart
child: showThisWidget? ElevatedButton(....) :null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Visibility` Widget to remove the button from the screen like:

```
bool visible = true;

void makeItUnvisible() {
     setState(() {
         visible = false;
     });
}

Visibility(
     visible: visible,
     child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: makeItUnvisible,
            child: const Text('Button Text'),
     ),
),
```